# Would shouldComponentUpdate make my page scroll more smoothly?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component with lots of child components, each with content (text, tables, inline styles) that don't change.

Because there is so much content being rendered, the page stutters when the user scrolls down the page. I want to make it smoother.

Would adding a `shouldComponentUpdate` have any impact on the scrolling smoothness?

My guess is "no", since `shouldComponentUpdate` occurs when updating the virtual DOM, and the virtual DOM is not updated on scroll.

**Note:** I don't have any state in the app that would change when the user scrolls.

Comment: You might look into this https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized for rendering your components

Comment: I think you answered yourself pretty well. The problem with the scolling has probably something to do with the page being too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding shouldComponentUpdate alone would not help you at all here.  I would look into something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinity.